# What's the purpose of returning a function from a function?

Tags: javascript

Reading some legacy code, and found

```
A.prototype.setSize: function () {
   var v1 = new Vector2();
   return function (size ) {

     var halfSize = v1.copy( size ).multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
     this.min.sub( halfSize );
     return this;

   };

}(),
```

I am wondering:

1. why define setSize as a function which return another function
2. Also the defined function is executed right away.

any light to shed on this?

Updated:

I can simply use

```
   A.prototype.setSize: function (size) {
       var v1 = new Vector2();

       var halfSize = v1.copy( size ).multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
       this.min.sub( halfSize );
       return this;

    },
```

Is the first snippet better than second?

Comment: If you need to optimise `setSize` then the first closure version is probably better. I find it less readable though, so if if performance isn't necessary I'd just use your second flatter version.

Answer (score 5):

1. So the returned function can access the value of `v1` each time it is called without making `v1` a global (or otherwise non-private)
2. That is so the returned function is assigned to `setSize`

Comment: I don't need to set v1 as global, I can just use var v1?

Comment: @AdamLee — You have to put the `var` statement *somewhere*. There isn't anywhere other then the closure to put it that either (a) Wouldn't make it available to other code or (b) Would recreate it each time `setSize` was called.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose in that particular case is to avoid creating a new `Vector` object each time `setSize` is called. It's a caching strategy. The alternative would be to just have a flat function:

```
A.prototype.setSize: function (size) {
  var v1 = new Vector2();
  var halfSize = v1.copy(size).multiplyScalar(0.5);
  this.min.sub(halfSize);
  return this;
}
```

I would only use the closure cached version of `setSize` if I found I was having performance problems because of `new Vector2()`.

Answer (score 2):

A classic example is:

```
function createAdder(x) {
  return function add(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

var addTwo = createAdder(2);
// addTwo is a function that takes one input and adds 2 to it
addTwo(3); // 5
addTwo(9); // 11
```

The idea is that you want to create a function, but the function you want to create depends on something. In this case, we wanted to create an `addX` function.

See [Chapter 5 of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) for more. Particularly the [Higher Order Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_xxCc98lOBK) section.

---

It also can be more DRY. Consider:

```
function createSecretAdder() {
  var secretNumber = generateSecretNumber(); // THIS TAKES A LONG TIME
  return function(n) {
    return secretNumber + n;
  }
}
var secretAdder = createSecretAdder(); // slow
secretAdder(2); // fast
secretAdder(7); // fast
```

vs.

```
function createSecretAdder() {
  return function(n) {
    var secret = getSecretNumber(); // THIS TAKES A LONG TIME
    return secretNumber + n;
  }
}
var secretAdder = createSecretAdder(); // fast
secretAdder(2); // slow
secretAdder(7); // slow
```

The former is DRYer and faster than the latter. This should address your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953717/whats-the-purpose-of-returning-a-function-from-a-function/31953753#comment51816952_31953734) and the update to your question.

Note: you'll have to understand [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to understand how this stuff works.

---

As for why it's immediately invoked, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

It function closure. Used to hide variables from global scope. Read on and see some examples here

[JS function closures](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)